# Resize website to fit into iframe

Tags: iframe, web, resize

Yes I know no one likes iframes, but here's the scenario.
I have a client who has his website that he's never going to change.
He has page that has an iframe with a 680px width and 600px height.
He currently has a website embedded in it that has a width of 950px.

What I want to know is if there is a way (I've searched all over) to automatically set the website to fit into the iframe box?

I have access to the child site but not to the parent, but my client actually knows some html/css so I can build a test link on my server and send him the code (if he needs it) to be applied on his end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to take a look at 'fluid' css design - if it's a fixed 950px, it'll never be able to fit in a smaller space. Search for fluid CSS.

Comment: I think this will be my best bet for this site. I'll go ahead and try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an "automatic" way, but one thing you could do is apply some CSS to the little page. If the page you are loading doesn't change, you can apply CSS that is specific to that page which will change the elements' widths, and anything else that needs to be changed. [Here is an answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217833/377628) that describes just how to do that for iframes.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've tried a few of the top suggestions on there but unfortunately they didn't work. Thanks again.